# Live curious or live curiously?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Why does national geographic use "live curious" instead of "live curiously"? I suppose we should use adverbs to describe verbs.

Comment: Hi, Roman. Welcome to English Language & Usage. Can you include the full sentence you heard or read? Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Related: [Is Apple's Old Slogan, "Think Different", grammatically incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/is-apples-old-slogan-think-different-grammatically-incorrect)

Comment: I'm doing this as a comment, as it isn't a well-formed answer.  To me "live curious" implies "be inquiring about things throughout your life".  The alternative could be misinterpreted as "live in a way that other people would find strange".

Answer (score 1):

In the one  hand, this is very simple. There is a trend in US advertising to drop the LY adverbs and use the adjective instead. That would not be acceptable in a formal essay but it's OK in advertising as it reflects the way people talk. Play Fair, instead of play fairly. But, on the other, there are amusing things like: Think Big, which is not an example of this, since there is no bigly and Think Big is a colloquial expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intriguing example where an ambiguous adverb serves less well than incorrect grammar.

**Live *curiously*** is correct but ambiguous, as seen at
[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/curiously):

> *curiously* – adverb
>
> 1. in an unusual and interesting way
> 2. in a way that shows that you want to find out about something

**Live *curious*** incorrectly modifies a verb, *live*, with an adjective, *curious*, but is unambiguously and readily understood.

The true answer to your question, “Why does National Geographic use
‘live curious’ ...,” is probably that “be curious”
doesn't satisfy high advertising standards.